# duplicating input url in append dataframe after scraping

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The scraping is working (website with a list of 6 products), however I would like to also append the baseurl to the dataframe at the end. Ideally at the end of the dataframe. I do not care about the header name.In the future I will have multiple urls in the "urls."

How can I do this?

Before:

```
0 1        2
1 product1 h
2 product2 t
3 product3 t
4 product4 p
5 product5 s
6 product6 :
```

After:

```
0 1        2
1 product1 baseurl
2 product2 baseurl
3 product3 baseurl
4 product4 baseurl
5 product5 baseurl
6 product6 baseurl
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from pandas import DataFrame


urls = [
    'this is where the site url is'
] 

final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Documents/python/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
        driver.get(url)
        soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        items  = soup.select('.grid-item-content')
        titles  = [item.text.strip() for item in items]
        baseurl = url
        results = list(zip(titles,baseurl))
        final.append([results])
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv(r'output.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
driver.quit()
```

print(titles):

```
[product1,product2,product3,product4,product5,product6]
```

print(baseurl):

```
[url] <--- only has one result
```

Comment: What you probably need is changing `list(zip(titles,baseurl))` this to `list(zip(titles,[baseurl] * len(titles)))`

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani - you just answered my 130+ words question in just 13 words. Really appreciate the help. Ive been stuck with this for the past 4 hours. This made my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

`list(zip(titles,baseurl))`

to

`list(zip(titles,[baseurl] * len(titles)))`

So that every element in the url gets a copy of the baseurl during zipping